# ライブラリslycot やcontrol や pyserial をインストールしたい

Tags: python3, anaconda, jupyter-lab

環境はmacOS,python3です。Anaconda Navigator からJupyter labを開き、slycot やcontrol や pyserial をインストールして使いたいのですが、Jupyter labのターミナルに以下のように入力してもエラーが出ます。Anaconda NavigatorのEnvironmentから同じことをしてもダメでした。

```
conda install -c conda-forge slycot
conda install -c conda-forge control
conda install pyserial
```

表示されるエラーは以下の通りです。

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

Comment: これらの記事 [Errors such as: 'Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve' & 'unittest' tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60300787/9014308), [Python Anacondaのインストールと仮想環境を操作する頻出コマンド9つ](https://hk29.hatenablog.jp/entry/2020/07/23/143342) の最後の方に書かれていることが参考になるかも。

Comment: それから、Anaconda全体を今の最新 [Anaconda|Individual Edition](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) のものに入れ替えてみてはどうでしょう？ Windows用で2020.11の版では、Terminalでconda環境の更新はしましたが、Anaconda.NavigatorのGUIで3つともインストール出来てjupyterlabでのimportも正常に出来ています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。